# Is there a way not to lost fragmen's viewmodel during orientation change?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am folloing MVVM architecture and I have a fragment attached to its parent activity. During orintation change, my fragment lost its viewmodel's instance and is createing a new one. How can I fix this?
Here is my activity.

```
class TestingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginPageViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing)

        loginViewModel=ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginPageViewModel::class.java)

        loginViewModel.getApiTokenRest(20234561, "ladevi31")
        TempDataStorage.initializeSharedPreferences(this)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PersonalInfFragment()).commit()

    }

}
```

Here is my example fragment that is attached to the activity every time orientation changes

```
class PersonalInfFragment : Fragment(R.layout.personal_information) {

    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var linearContainer: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var showLinearLayout: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var personalViewModel: InformationViewModel
    private lateinit var myOnBackPressed: MyOnBackPressed
    private lateinit var tool_bar: Toolbar
    private val TAG = "PersonalInfFragment"


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initProperties(view)
        initToolBar()
        initObservingPersonalInformation()
        initBackButton()
        Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${personalViewModel.hashCode()}")
    }

    private fun initObservingPersonalInformation() {
        personalViewModel.returnPersonalInformation().observe(this) {
            if (it != null) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                showLinearLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                for (k in PersonalInformation::class.memberProperties) {
                    val text = TextView(requireActivity())
                    text.setLayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        )
                    )
                    text.text = "${k.name}:${k.get(it)}"
                    Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${text.text}")
                    text.textSize = 20.0f
                    linearContainer.addView(text)
                    Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: ${TempDataStorage.getCurUser()?.urlToken}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initProperties(view: View) {
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
        linearContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.parent_linear)
        showLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.show_linear)
        personalViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(InformationViewModel::class.java)
        personalViewModel.startRequesting()
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        showLinearLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        tool_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar)
        tool_bar.title = ""

        Log.i(TAG, "initProperties PersonalFragment: ${personalViewModel.hashCode()}")

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your fragment and activity?

Comment: Have a look at [SavedStateHandle guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate). You can save your view model's variables into it. It is designed for config and orientation changes. SavedStateHandle content is not saved permanently.

Comment: That should not happen. Need to see your code.

Comment: Maybe I doing something wrong, here is code I 've edited please, take a loot it.

Comment: Please explain what "my fragment lost its viewmodel's instance and is createing a new one" means.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen as

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as `screen rotations`.

try not initializing viewModel every time like

```kotlin
if(!this::viewmodel.isInitialized) // initialize
```